# Visual Studio npm modules

Tags: typescript, npm, reactjs, react-dnd

I am using Visual Studio to develop a project. I am using react with typescript. In *.jsx files some of npm modules are giving error like :

> Cannot find module 'react-dnd'

I have already installed react-dnd to node_modules. But I cannot stop getting this error.

Here is my code.

```
import * as React from "react"
import BaseComponent from "../BaseComponent"
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import Container from '../../Components/Container';
import Box from '../../Components/Box';
```

3rd and 4th lines are causing error. In addition I will share my tsconfig file below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "inlineSources": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noLib": false,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/ts"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "include": [
    "ScriptLib/Components/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How exactly did you install the `react-dnd` module? Did you do it via `npm install --save react-dnd`?

Comment: Yes i did it like you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the type definitions for these libraries:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-dnd
npm install --save-dev @types/react-dnd-html5-backend
```

Comment: do every package have own type definition file like your wrote?

Comment: Some libraries have separate definition files (ex. above). Some have definitions along with the library (ex. angular). Some don't have definition files. [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) has a big collection of type definitions for most libraries.

Comment: Thanks for explanation